# Function needs double click to trigger

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following situation: i have to click twice on the button to trigger the function that adds the data into localStorage formular's content. Could you explain to me why is this button behaving like this and how can i remediate this problem?

here is the javascript code:

```
async function addMovieIntoBrowser() {
  const valueName = document.getElementById("fname");
  const valueDescription = document.getElementById("fdescription");
  const valueYear = document.getElementById("fyear");
  const valueRating = document.getElementById("frating");
  const buttonInsert = document.getElementById("buttonInsert");

  buttonInsert.onclick = async function () {
    const name = valueName.value;
    const description = valueDescription.value;
    const image = await returnImage(name);
    const year = valueYear.value;
    const rating = valueRating.value;

    if (name && description && image && year && rating) {
      localStorage.setItem("Name", name);
      localStorage.setItem("Description", description);
      localStorage.setItem("Image", image);
      localStorage.setItem("Year", year);
      localStorage.setItem("Rating", rating);
      localStorage.setItem("Date added", new Date().toLocaleString());

      const table = document.getElementById("completedTable");
      const row = table.insertRow(0);
      const cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      const cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      const cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
      const cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
      const cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
      const cell6 = row.insertCell(5);

      cell1.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Name");
      cell2.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Description");
      cell3.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Image");
      cell4.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Year");
      cell5.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Rating");
      cell6.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Date added");

      const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(
        "#fyear, #fname,#fdescription, #frating"
      );
      inputs.forEach((input) => {
        input.value = "";
      });
```

Comment: you can create a variable set it to 0 and on click increase by 1 if double click so var = 2 then check if var is 2 then trigger the function or event

Comment: You assign the button click  function in the addMovieIntoBrowser. How do you call addMovieIntoBrowser

Comment: Please click [edit], then the icon that looks like `[<>]` and provide us with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `localStorage` here as you are using the contents straight away on the same page. In fact, you can simplify your script considerably: Below is a short working example without the "image" column. As the film image seems to be supplied in form of a promise it can also be included by using `await`.

```js
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("#fyear, #fname,#fdescription, #frating")],
 tbl=document.querySelector("#tbl");

document.querySelector("button").onclick=async ()=>{ 
 tbl.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<tr><td>"+
 inputs.map(inp=>inp.value).join("</td><td>")+"</td></tr>");
 inputs.forEach(inp=>inp.value="");
};
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" value="2020" id="fyear"> year<br>
<input type="text" value="Roma" id="fname"> name<br>
<input type="text" value="an epic film" id="fdescription"> description<br>
<input type="text" value="5" id="frating"> rating
</form><button>add</button>
<h2>Film table</h2>
<table><thead><tr><th>year</th><th>name</th><th>description</th><th>rating</th></tr></thread>
<tbody id="tbl"></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Template literals are nicer in my opinion https://stackoverflow.com/a/73176513/295783

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler

```js
const tbl = document.getElementById("tbl"),
  form = document.querySelector("form"),
  inputs = [...form.elements];

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  tbl.innerHTML += `<tr>${inputs
    .map(({value}) => `<td>${value}</td>`)
    .join("")}</tr>`;
    form.reset();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="" name="fyear"> year<br>
  <input type="text" value="" name="fname"> name<br>
  <input type="text" value="" name="fdescription"> description<br>
  <input type="text" value="" name="frating"> rating
</form><button>add</button>
<h2>Film table</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>year</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>description</th>
      <th>rating</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbl"></tbody>
</table>
```